# NoReverseMatch error with password reset emails

Tags: python, django

I have been trying to create a system for password reset emails. I have been following this [tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/09/19/how-to-create-password-reset-view.html).

I am getting this error when I try to visit `/password/reset/`:

> django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'password_reset_done' not found. 'password_reset_done' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Here are the relevant URL patterns in *urls.py*:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', auth_views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^password/reset/$', auth_views.password_reset, name='reset_password'),
    url(r'^password/reset/done/$', auth_views.password_reset_done, name='password_reset_done'),
    url(r'^password/reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', auth_views.password_reset_confirm, name='password_reset_confirm'),
    url(r'^password/reset/complete/$', auth_views.password_reset_complete, name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

How do I make this page render correctly?

Comment: auth_views is built into django @OmarEinea

Comment: just saw that in the tutorial ;)

Comment: have you imported `from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views` @cbuch1800

Comment: @wtreston yes, just approved the edit to show that.

Comment: try chaning `name='rest_password'` to `name=password_reset`

Comment: ah @OmarEinea beat me to it :)

Comment: @wtreston this has not worked.

Comment: let me see your settings.py installed_app and your EMAIL_BACKEND option

Comment: @RoelDelosReyes `django.contrib.auth` is installed and `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'`

Comment: if you are using pycharm, ctrl+click the `views` of  `from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views` and look for `password_reset_done` view. That  error says it couldnt be found maybe your are trying to import a wrong module?