# NoReverseMatch errors during Django forgot password email system

Tags: python, django, forgot-password

I am trying to create a system for resetting forgotten passwords through email but am getting some errors.

My urls are:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', auth_views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, name='logout'),
    ## more irrelevant urls here ##
    url(r'^password/reset/done/$', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
    url(r'^password/reset/$', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
    url(r'^password/reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    url(r'^password/reset/complete/$', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

When the email address is submitted at `password_reset`, the email sends but I get this error:

```
Internal Server Error: /password/reset/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 67, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 149, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 63, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py", line 439, in dispatch
    return super(PasswordResetView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 183, in post
    return self.form_valid(form)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py", line 453, in form_valid
    return super(PasswordResetView, self).form_valid(form)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 79, in form_valid
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 67, in get_success_url
    if self.success_url:
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 114, in __wrapper__
    res = func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 91, in reverse
    return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 497, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'password_reset_done' not found. 'password_reset_done' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
[11/Feb/2018 14:32:04] "POST /password/reset/ HTTP/1.1" 500 121086
```

When I copy the link into the browser and reset the password, the password resets correctly but the following error appears:

```
Internal Server Error: /password/reset/MQ/set-password/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 67, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\debug.py", line 76, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 63, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 67, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 57, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 63, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py", line 489, in dispatch
    return super(PasswordResetConfirmView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 183, in post
    return self.form_valid(form)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py", line 522, in form_valid
    return super(PasswordResetConfirmView, self).form_valid(form)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 79, in form_valid
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 67, in get_success_url
    if self.success_url:
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 114, in __wrapper__
    res = func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 91, in reverse
    return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 497, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'password_reset_complete' not found. 'password_reset_complete' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
[11/Feb/2018 14:37:16] "POST /password/reset/MQ/set-password/ HTTP/1.1" 500 134868
```

Technically the system functions, but obviously these error messages are not ideal.

These are the other questions I have asked about this:

[NoReverseMatch error with password reset emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48720943/noreversematch-error-with-password-reset-emails)

[Error with system for email password resets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48729812/error-with-system-for-email-password-resets)

And this is the [tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/09/19/how-to-create-password-reset-view.html) I followed.

Comment: maybe you have this url file  inside an app ?

Comment: @LeLouch yes it's in an app called elections. Should it not be?

Comment: The tutorial you link to doesn't use class-based-views..?  Also noticed that `/password/reset/MQ/set-password/` matches your `password_reset_confirm` url...

Comment: @thebjorn I was getting NoReverseMatch errors before I switched to class-based views as well. I'm fairly certain that using the class-based version of these views is not the cause of these errors. Also, is the url not supposed to match?

Comment: well since i can't see your file structure and your full urls , having this urls inside your main url file should solve your problem

Comment: @LeLouch Thanks for the suggestion, that has worked. I would rather have them contained within my app though, is this at all possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still possible in newer Djangos, but in previous versions we've done this:

```
# django login views
urlpatterns += patterns(
    'django.contrib.auth.views',
    url(r'^logout/$',
        'logout',
        dict(
            template_name='my/logout.html',
            redirect_field_name='next',
        )),

    url(r'^password-reset/$',
        'password_reset',
        dict(
            template_name='my/password-reset-form.html',
            email_template_name='my/password-reset-email.html',
            subject_template_name='my/password-reset-email-subject.html',
            from_email=settings.FROM_EPOST,
        ),
        name="my-password-reset"),

    url(r'^password-reset-done/$',
        'password_reset_done',
        dict(
            template_name='my/password-reset-done.html',
        )),

    url(r'^password-reset-confirm/(?P<uidb64>.+)/(?P<token>.+)/$',
        'password_reset_confirm',
        dict(
            template_name='my/password-reset-confirm.html',
            # post_reset_redirect='url',
        )),

    url(r'^password-reset-complete/$',
        'password_reset_complete',
        dict(
            template_name='my/password-reset-complete.html',
        )),
)
```

I seem to remember there was an issue with having slashes in these urls, but it's been a long time since I wrote those..

The email template contains:

```
{% block reset_link %}
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are getting no reversematch because the password_reset function is redirecting to ('password_reset_done') instead of your app namespace
for full detail you can check the docs in [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urlresolvers/)

for instance if your include url for election app looks like that :

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'election', include(election.urls, namespace="SomeName")),

]
```

you can solve the problem by removing the name/namespace in your include url or need you need to override the password_reset function.
 from django.contrib.auth.view import password_reset

```
#views.py
def new_password_reset(password_reset):
    if post_reset_redirect is None:
        post_reset_redirect = reverse('SomeName:password_reset_done')

    return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, context) 

#urls.py
from election import views as election_views
#and in your urls change that url:
url(r'^password_reset/$', auth_views.password_reset, name='password_reset')

#with that url :
url(r'^password_reset/$', election_views.new_password_reset, name='password_reset')
```

and you should be all right